# how to Extract a string variable from QRCode Result Set in Android using ZXing?

Tags: java, android, arrays, qr-code, zxing

Currently in my app I am getting the QR extracted result as

**abcd,cbhsdk,shyuiod,hsjsk:,DOJ:22-May-2015,kjlakjdlkajsd,dfkjdsakjds**

Expected result: 22-May-2015 into a string
My current code to get string DOJ is as shown below
**

```
enter code here
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        Log.e("handler", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        Log.e("handler", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode)
                   // Assigning the required vales from result *************
        String[] arrayOfResultString = new String[1];
        arrayOfResultString[0] = rawResult.getText();
        String[] arrayOfResultStringDOJ = arrayOfResultString[0].split("DOJ:");
        if ((arrayOfResultStringPNR.length > 1) && (arrayOfResultStringPNR[1].length() >= 10) )
        {
            String DOJ= arrayOfResultStringPNR[1].substring(0, 10);

        }
```

**
The challenge for this code is DOJ position may vary during different QR scans.
Kindly help me with the solution.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, "please write my java code" isn't exactly what we do here.  Please [edit] your question with some java code that you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI : QR code library give result which stored in QR code so here you got above result.

If you need only PNR value then spit string with ",".

So you will get PNR No.:4408321486

Now remove "PNR No.:" from above string.

Comment: Thanks a lot Viram, I got it working. Is there a way to extract the Date Of Journey also from the result set.